# Get all keys values using yq if a given string matches in YAML

Tags: yaml, yq

I have below yaml file and I am trying to get all key value pairs if  `abc` string is present in values.

```
a: abcsdf
b: hyuabc
c: iopabc
d: mnhbvgc
```

Expected output:

```
a: abcsdf
b: hyuabc
c: iopabc
```

My Attempt:

```
yq eval '.[] | select(. == "*abc*") test.yaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really weird, the [`select`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/select#select-and-update-matching-values-in-map) and [`del`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/delete#delete-matching-entries) functions in  work totally different. While select returns the result of the filter as the array elements, delete returns the map

```
yq eval 'del( .[] | select( . != "*abc*" ) )' yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`yq 'select(.[] == "*abc*")'`

(go version, v4.30.8)